# Column width less than minmax

Tags: css, css-grid

If I decrease the width of the container why do cells take less than 200px?

I think ***minmax*** must keep width not less than first parameter (200px).

If delete styles for `.a`,  `.k` and `.g` everything is ok.

https://codepen.io/rachelandrew/pen/GZQYQa

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr) ) ;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: white;
}

.a {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
}

.k {
  grid-column: auto / span 3;
}

.g {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
  grid-row: auto / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
  <div class="box g">G</div>
  <div class="box h">H</div>
  <div class="box i">I</div>
  <div class="box j">J</div>
  <div class="box k">K</div>
  <div class="box l">L</div>
  <div class="box m">M</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not `minmax()`. The problem is `auto-fill` or the `grid-column` / `grid-row` additions.

If you switch from:

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
```

To, let's say:

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(200px, 1fr));
```

…then the `200px` minimum is respected ([codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bKqmQY)).

The 200px minimum is not respected with `auto-fill` for reasons described in the Grid spec (although I'm not 100% sure of this).

> [**§ 7.2.2.2. Repeat-to-fill: `auto-fill` and `auto-fit`
>   repetitions**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-repeat)
>
> When `auto-fill` is given as the repetition number, if the grid
>   container has a definite size or max size in the relevant axis, then
>   the number of repetitions is the largest possible positive integer
>   that does not cause the grid to overflow its grid container (treating
>   each track as its **max track sizing function** if that is definite or
>   as its minimum track sizing function otherwise, and taking `gap` into
>   account).
>
> <sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So, let's break this down:

1. I believe the container does have a [definite size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#definite), as it is a block element, so it takes the width of its parent.
2. Each track is taking the [max track sizing function](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#max-track-sizing-function), which is the second argument in the `minmax()` function. In this case, that's `1fr`.
3. But the spec says *"...treating each track as its max track sizing function if that is definite..."*. I am not sure that `1fr` is considered a [definite size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#definite) in this scenario, so I can't be certain that this rule applies. It looks like it applies, based on the output, but this may not be the reason.
4. Another twist is the fact that the 200px `minmax()` minimum with `auto-fill` actually works if the `grid-column` and `grid-row` additions are removed ([codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zaZeoJ)).

I'm guessing there's more to this behavior outlined in the spec.

Answer (score 0):

`auto-fill` and `auto-fit` create implicit grid (I'm not sure. I found nothing about it in spec).

Next line fixes the problem

`grid-auto-columns: minmax(200px, 1fr);`